# How to close a Pygame window without closing Tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

For my project, I have a Tkinter window as the main menu, from which, a pygame window can be launched. In the pygame window, a simulation runs with a conditional infinite main loop.
I want to have a stop functionality so that the user can close the pygame window and be able to start a new one, however, if I call `pygame.quit()` (or `sys.exit()` or `pygame.display.quit()`) in the pygame program, it closes the Tkinter window as well, which I'd want to stay open.

I have tried to embed the pygame program into a `Toplevel` window, but after I stop the pygame main loop and call `destroy()` on the `Toplevel` window it closes, but the main Tk window freezes and will not respond to any user input, but code execution continues after calling `destroy()`.

#### Pygame

Main loop

```py
def run(self):
        while not self.exit_flag:

            self.display.fill(GREY)
            self.draw_text()
            self.draw_obstacles()

            self.pygame_event_check()  # a method for checking if event.type == pygame.QUIT

            if self.running:               #self.running is for pausing the window
                if self.counter >= self.lifespan:   # create new generation for simulation
                    self.counter = 0
                    new_generation, finished = self.rocket_pop.selection()
                    self.rocket_pop = Population(new_generation)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.gen_count += 1

                    if finished > 0 and self.reached_goal == False:     # tracking the first generation to reach the goal
                        print(f"Reached the goal in {self.gen_count} generations")
                        self.reached_goal = True


                for rocket in self.rocket_pop.population:    # runs the update method on all individuals
                    rocket.update(self.counter)

                self.counter += 1                            # keeping track of the lifetime of the rockets

                self.clock.tick(self.fps)
                pygame.draw.circle(self.display, PINK, self.target, 20)     # draw the goal
                pygame.display.update()

        print("exit")
```

Simulation start procedure

```py
def run():     
    main = Main()
    mThread = threading.Thread(target=main.run)  # I get a "PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate" error if I just call main.run()
    mThread.start()
    mThread.join()
```

#### Tkinter

Setup

```py
import tkinter as tk
from genetic_stuff import *


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        start = tk.Button(self.master, text="Start", command = self.run_simulation)
        stop = tk.Button(self.master, text="Stop", command = self.stop_simulation)

        start.place(x=10, y=10, w=100, h=45)
        stop.place(x=240, y=10, w=100, h=45)

        ...

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Start/ Stop simulation

```py
    def run_simulation(self):
        self.sim_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)

        embed = tk.Frame(self.sim_window, width = Main.window_width, height = Main.window_height) 
        embed.pack()
        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
        run()                                         
        self.sim_window.update()

    def stop_simulation(self):
        Main.exit_flag = True
        self.sim_window.destroy()
        self.sim_window.update()
```

links to pastebins of full code for replicating:

- [genetic_stuff.py](https://pastebin.com/FauRuBFh)
- [tkinterface.py](https://pastebin.com/s7q3is81)

pics for reference:

- [Main menu before interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2oK7.png)
- [Simulation running in a Toplevel window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngcVJ.png)
- [Main menu stuck after closing Toplevel window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8x3L.png)

Comment: I suspect `while` is your problem.

Comment: You have 2 different functions called `run()` that may also be a problem. `Main.window_width` does not make sense. Main is a class. I think you mean `main.window_width` with a lower case. That said `main` is only a local variable to `run()` I am not sure it will work as expected. Also this line `self.sim_window.update()` can only ever error.

Comment: Move `self.sim_window.destroy()` inside `def run(self):` right after `print("exit")`. Also remove both `self.sim_window.update()`

Comment: I have a similar app that combines a GTK window that controls things and displays numeric data, with a pygame window that displays the animations and graphics. I did not embed the pygame window in the GTK, window, I just let pygame manage it's own window. That way when my simulation stops and destroys the pygame window, GTK is not affected.